# erl with centos "Failed to create main carrier for ll_alloc"

Tags: linux, centos, rabbitmq, vps, erl

i am having a centos vps. i have installed erlang
by the command

```
rpm -Uvh erlang-17.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Now whenever i try to run my rabbitmq-server. or i just issue erl command 
then i get this error.

> Failed to create main carrier for ll_alloc Aborted

is it some memory issue erlang is unable to get free memory or what?

here are memory stats of the machine

```
sudo cat /proc/meminfo

MemTotal:        4194304 kB
MemFree:          104520 kB
Cached:          2718800 kB
Buffers:               0 kB
Active:          1729508 kB
Inactive:        2170684 kB
Active(anon):     559168 kB
Inactive(anon):   627436 kB
Active(file):    1170340 kB
Inactive(file):  1543248 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                44 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1186604 kB
Shmem:              5212 kB
Slab:             189472 kB
SReclaimable:     155768 kB
SUnreclaim:        33704 kB
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out it was a memory issue when i shutdown tomcat to make available few more mbs of memory than the erl started.