# ejabberd 16.01 postinstall.sh fails on centos 7

Tags: linux, erlang, ejabberd, centos7

I've just installed ejabberd 16.01 on my CentOS 7.1.1503, I have used the rpm installer downloaded from ProcessOne's web site using:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh ejabberd-16.01-0.x86_64.rpm
```

The installation went well up until the end, but finally I got an error message (without any description). I took a look into /opt/ejabberd-16.01 and saw everything was in it's place so I've tried running /bin/postinstall.sh manually to see what might go wrong.

When I run the script I get the following output:

```
   -=- ejabberd post installation script -=-
          (c) 2005-2015 ProcessOne

* Checking ejabberd installation
usermod: no changes

* Starting ejabberd instance
Failed to create main carrier for ll_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
Failed to create main carrier for ll_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
Failed to create main carrier for ll_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
Failed to create main carrier for ll_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
Failed to create main carrier for ll_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
Failed to create main carrier for ll_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
Failed to create main carrier for ll_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
Failed to create main carrier for ll_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I get a familiar experience when I start the ejabbered server using:

```
ejabberdctl start
```

and then when I try to use ejabberdctl again (to stop/register a user) I get the same result:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnxWT.png)

From searching around I've found some connection to memory issues ([erl with centos Failed to create main carrier for ll_alloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30375695/erl-with-centos-failed-to-create-main-carrier-for-ll-alloc))

but this doesn't seem to be the case since I have 1GB of RAM and this is the output of top command: [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvG7X.png)
so as you can see I have 573MB of free RAM (shouldn't it be enough??)

any help would be very much appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: My guess is that you Ram is not enough to run installer + ejabberd.

Comment: I had some fear that it might be it but shouldn't 500mb be enough for the installer script? I figured it shouldn't consume so much memory. I'll try to run it on a diffrent machine with bigger memory to if this is the case. If it's realy the case, do you know if it's really necessary? Maybe it (either erl, ejabber or the installer script) could be configured to consume less? What are the minimum requirements for ejabbed anyway?TThanks!

Comment: 500 mb is not just the installer. Installer also runs ejabberd itself to perform configuration operations.